# Saving state for each page of a view pager properly

Tags: android, android-viewpager, state-management, android-viewpager2

I have a view pager and each page selects user input. It is based on views and not fragment and is inside an `Activity`.
I want at the final step to collect all the user selections from all the pages.
How can I keep the selections and be able to properly update them if the user goes back/forth the viewpager?

Comment: Can you please share your code so I can help you, btw you can use the hashmap to hold the states that might be helpful to you

Comment: @ErselanKhan:I thought of having a hashmap, but how would that help with rotations etc? I didn't post any code because I don't need detailed code as an answer and it might make the post more confusing as people might think I am interested in a specific way

Comment: @ErselanKhan: I mean I am ok with a high level answer

Comment: You can set your hashmap inside your ViewModel class :)

Comment: @ErselanKhan: Could you elaborate a bit on the design?

Comment: You can use a `HashMap` or a `Pair` & if you want configuration safety like rotation, etc then you should add your data-related logic in your `ViewModel` & probably expose the same via a `LiveData`. Check here for ViewModel: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Comment: @DarShan: So the ViewPager has one ViewModel? Or is it a ViewModel per page?

Comment: I'd suggest keeping a single `ViewModel` if you are only using a single Activity for this task.

Comment: @DarShan: What would be the difference with having a hashmap and save it `onSaveInstanceState`?

Comment: onSaveInstanceState is not recommended for large data

Comment: @ErselanKhan:Where does ViewModel store data that it allows large data?